# Closure properties of CFL

Tags: automata

Show that L = {w ∈ {a, b, c}∗ | |w|a = |w|b = |w|c} is not context-free by using the closure properties of the context-free languages.
Note: make sure to use the closure properties of the context-free languages.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site, as I think you've misunderstood what this website is for. StackOverflow is a *programming-specific* site, and your question doesn't appear to be related to the kinds of questions that should be on this site. You're more likely to find an answer on the [CS Stack Exchange site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), though I warn you that they'll probably want to be shown more effort than the zero you've put into this question here.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/116972/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you know that a^n b^n c^n is not a context-free language (this can be proven separately using the pumping lemma for context-free languages; this is probably as close to a canonical non-context-free language as you're likely to find). Note that this non-CFL is the intersection of your language and the regular language a*b*c*. But the intersection of a CFL with a regular language must be a CFL (this is the closure property). This is a contradiction, so your language cannot be a CFL.

Generally, my gut says that to prove something is NOT a CFL using closure properties implies you MUST use something like contradiction and you MUST have a language you know is not a CFL that your reasoning would indicate must be. I don't see another way of proving the negative with closure properties alone.